# log cron job in real time

Tags: 14.04, cron, log, logging

I have a Python process which I run nightly via a crontab. It scrapes an API which I have limited access to so regularly has to stop and wait for an hour.

By my estimates the job should take 5-6 hours to complete.

At the moment I have a crontab as such:

```
05 01 * * * python3 /home/{my username}/path/to/process/main.py >> /var/log/process_name.log 2>&1
```

This is great and has proven to show that the file runs, but I can only check the output after it has finished running, which for me is not ideal. Considering the time it takes to run I would prefer cron to log output and errors in real time.

This is a bit more of a problem now as it seems my estimates are off and I can be waiting far longer than I think I should - in which case I would like to see what is being logged so I can understand why.

Is there a way to log cron output in real time?

Comment: Have you tried to flush the output? `import sys` followed by `sys.stdout.flush()` in your python program.

Comment: @jos good point and I could potentially do that, although Ideally I would eventually move this into a `bash` script to runs some `SQL` as well, at which point flushing through `py` wouldn't work.

Comment: Shell scripts flush on a line by line basis. Does that help?

Comment: Allow me to convert this to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a mechanism called flushing: forcing a process to write its output, which would otherwise remain buffered until completion.

Shell scripts flush on a line by line basis. If you need the output of a shell script before the script is ended, make sure it contains a newline.

Python programs can explicitly flush their stdout by calling the flush method:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```